# C++11 Avoiding Redundant Return Type in specific Situation

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, return-type-deduction, trailing-return-type

Ok, thanks everyone who has looked at this. I've recreated the exact scenario for easy viewing at the link below, so I'll just comment out the original text I had as it wasn't clear.
http://cpp.sh/5lp4l

In the comment section I show calling make_some(32, std::string{"hi"}) without specifying the Data type declaration for the call. I realize this seems insane and way above my expected use case, automatically inferring the composite type (inferring I wanted Data, based on the int/string) based on the arguments wasn't necessary, or a good idea.

Comment: For `QueryResult<int, int>` what is the underlying `boost::optional` template parameter? Or in other words,iIf `QueryResult` is just a wrapper around `boost::optional`, how can it have more than one template parameter?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the compilation error you are seeing. There are too many unknowns in your question (the biggest one being the details of `QueryResult)`.  The comments you have written inside `somefn` don't make any sense.

Comment: `return QueryResult<T>(std::forward(args));` is certainly wrong, should be `return QueryResult<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`.

Comment: All the comments are right. I've posted a URL to a complete MVE, thanks!
http://cpp.sh/5lp4l

Comment: The problem with your assumption is that you **think** the right type to deduce is `Data` because it can be constructed from an `int` and an `std::string`. The problem is, so can `std::vector<std::string>` ! And you can't expect the compiler to check each and every possible type (including templated types) to see if it perhaps has a ctor which matches your arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is right. There's just no relation given between `T` and `Args`. Hence, it cannot determine what `QueryResult<T>` means.

What you apparently expect is that the return type of `somefn` forces `T` to be `int, int`. That's obviously not possible for two reasons: `T` denotes a single type, and there's just no mechanism by which the `return` statement somehow affects the template instantiation of `make_some`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `auto` as type declaration?

Also `decltype (variable_here) variable_to_inherit_type;` sets the type of the second variable to that of the first variable. You might be able to first set the type the same as the incoming variable using this.

I am not sure if this will work in your case but let me know if it helps!